# Search N consecutive rows with same value in one dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to create a python code to search "N" as variable, consecutive rows in a column dataframe with the same value and different that NaN like this.
I can't figure out how to do it with a for loop because I don't know which row I'm looking at in each case. Any idea that how can do it?

| Fruit | 2 matches | 5 matches |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | No | No |
| NaN | No | No |
| Pear | No | No |
| Pear | Yes | No |
| Pear | Yes | No |
| Pear | Yes | No |
| Pear | Yes | Yes |
| NaN | No | No |
| NaN | No | No |
| NaN | No | No |
| NaN | No | No |
| NaN | No | No |
| Banana | No | No |
| Banana | Yes | No |

**Update: testing solutions by @Corralien**

```
counts = (df.groupby(df['Fruit'].ne(df['Fruit'].shift()).cumsum()) # virtual groups
            .transform('cumcount').add(1)  # cumulative counter
            .where(df['Fruit'].notna(), other=0))  # set NaN to 0
N = 2
df['Matches'] = df.where(counts >= N, other='No')
```

VSCode return me the 'Frame skipped from debugging during step-in.' message when execute the last line and generate an exception in the previous for loop.

Comment: What is `N`? Explain more please

Comment: @sammywemmy. N is a variable for number of consecutive values in the `Fruit` column (except for NaN). The expected is the two other columns (I think)

Comment: Yes, N is a variable that can change your value  and indicates the # of consecutive fruit requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compute consecutive values and set NaN to 0. Once you have calculated the cumulative counter, you just have to check if the counter is greater than or equal to `N`:

```
counts = (df.groupby(df['Fruit'].ne(df['Fruit'].shift()).cumsum()) # virtual groups
            .transform('cumcount').add(1)  # cumulative counter
            .where(df['Fruit'].notna(), other=0))  # set NaN to 0

N = 2
df['2 matches'] = counts.ge(N).replace({True: 'Yes', False: 'No'})

N = 5
df['5 matches'] = counts.ge(N).replace({True: 'Yes', False: 'No'})
```

Output:

```
>>> df
     Fruit 2 matches 5 matches
0    Apple        No        No
1      NaN        No        No
2     Pear        No        No
3     Pear       Yes        No
4     Pear       Yes        No
5     Pear       Yes        No
6     Pear       Yes       Yes
7      NaN        No        No
8      NaN        No        No
9      NaN        No        No
10     NaN        No        No
11     NaN        No        No
12  Banana        No        No
13  Banana       Yes        No

>>> counts
0     1
1     0
2     1
3     2
4     3
5     4
6     5
7     0
8     0
9     0
10    0
11    0
12    1
13    2
dtype: int64
```

**Update**

> if I need to change "Yes" for the fruit name for example

```
N = 2
df['2 matches'] = df.where(counts >= N, other='No')
print(df)

# Output
     Fruit 2 matches
0    Apple        No
1      NaN        No
2     Pear        No
3     Pear      Pear
4     Pear      Pear
5     Pear      Pear
6     Pear      Pear
7      NaN        No
8      NaN        No
9      NaN        No
10     NaN        No
11     NaN        No
12  Banana        No
13  Banana    Banana
```

Comment: If you use `gt` you don't need the `add(1)` ;)

Comment: I have a doubt for N=1? (I know it doesn't make sense). but I can set NaN to -1 :-)

Comment: Yes or keep it NaN and change your condition to convert to yes/no

Comment: Too much work for me at this hour :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Runs perfectly!! I've a doubt, if I need to change "Yes" for the fruit name for example. Can change .replace({True: 'Yes', False: 'No'}) by .replace({True: df['ERC'], False: 'No'}) or adding new line condition?

Comment: Thanks for the update. It works perfectly in Colab individually, but not in my full VSC program. When running the first line "counts=" it goes to a for exception. I had a "SettingWithCopyWarning" warning before, but the application worked fine. Can this warning affect this new code?

Comment: No. However, take a look to https://stackoverflow.com/q/20625582/15239951

Comment: With your first solution now haven't any error and works fine, but when change to the update version returns the exception error again. It is posible to create this new '2 matches? DF column by .loc? I don't find how do it.

Comment: Please update your post with the traceback error.

Comment: Updated with the debug console message. Thanks a lot for your time to look it!

Comment: Can you try this version `df['2 matches'] = np.where(counts.ge(N), df['Fruit'], 'No')` please? Don't forget to `import numpy as np`

Comment: Now works perfect! I don't know the differences between this 2 methods, numpy should be strongest. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: It should have the same behavior but sometimes... :-)